# Percentage ticks in plotly without multiplying with 100

Tags: python, d3.js, plotly

I think I'm going crazy. I'm trying to configure the y-axis ticks for my plotly go bar chart.
It's a stacked bar chart with `barnorm='percent'`, meaning that all bars in total get up to a 100 %.
However, I can not seem to get the ticks to work correctly.

Reading [the documentation from plotly](https://plotly.com/python/tick-formatting/) gives nothing else than that they seem to think this is the default behavior and forward me to the underlying framework d3, which has [a rigorous system for defining ticks](https://github.com/d3/d3-format/blob/main/README.md#locale_format). Sadly, I can not understand a thing about it.

If I pick `tickformat='%'` in `update_layout`, the tick for 100 % is `10000.000000%`.

If I pick `tickformat='p'`, the tick for 100 % is `10000%`.

Both of those methods seem to multiply my value by 100. That is not what I want, since plotly has the correct number from start. I can not seem to figure out how it should be done, and I have put so much time into this now, I hope someone can help. My code is below:

```
animals=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys']

fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Bar(name='SF Zoo', x=animals, y=[20, 14, 23]),
    go.Bar(name='LA Zoo', x=animals, y=[12, 18, 29])
])

# Change the bar mode
fig.update_layout(
        barmode='stack',
        barnorm = 'percent',
        font_family="Roboto",
        font_size=15,
        yaxis = dict(tickformat='%'),
        showlegend=True
    )

fig.show()
```

(Tried to upload an image of the bar chart but got some server error from SO)

Comment: You want to add the percentage sign to the ticks of y-axis, right? because I removed `yaxis = dict(tickformat='%'),`, it works correctly with me without `%`.

Comment: @Hamzah Yes, that is what I want! Unfortunately, I can still not upload an image to show. But if I remove that setting the y-axis will have the number correct (100) but not have percentage signs, which is what I would like (100%).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove  `yaxis = dict(tickformat='%')`  and add the following:

```
fig.update_layout(yaxis_ticksuffix = '%')
```

You need to read more [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/plotly-axis-problems/38320/2) to know more about how Plotly works with percentage sign.

Comment: Thank you so much! Both for solution and link for reading. :)